# How to automatically grabbing the tasks from planner into Metrics/goal?

Tags: metrics, power-automate, microsoft-planner

Hi PowerAutomate/Flow experts,

In the planner there are following tasks from projects: Lavender, Marigold & Teal

[image: Abhi_2023_0-1700740158593.png]

The Goal is automatically get the tasks from planner into Metrics as below
[image: Abhi_2023_1-1700740195738.png]

In Flow:

Since there is no way to group the tasks for relevant projects, it is hard to map them on to Metrics using PowerAutomate:

[image: Abhi_2023_2-1700740231763.png]

We can group by Buckets or 1-1 tasks from Planner to Metrics but looking for ways to group tasks via either labels or something else !

UPDATE:
When used "gettask" to grab appliedCategories, there is no specific category shown in raw output. Also, how can we group such categories ? should we use a loop & condition ?

[image: raw output]

Added task with appliedcategories = Dark green (category18)

[image: planner with tast named task-planner]
[image: adding condition to check the task above added with appliedCategories] but still not catching it leading to escaping the condition too.

:(

[image: replicating the sam answer]...Not sure what Create Label here means and there is no current item from the Filter TaskbyLabel in new view

[image: error when replicated]

Thanks @Sam for your efforts to help us. It seems even after adding the expresssion, it lead to error.
[image: Get Plan Details- Bad Request]

Also, for the final step, is Output should be UniqueLabels ?
[image: FilterTaskByLabel step]

[image: 4 points]

#### Update

[image: error 1]

In the step above RenamedLabelNames....there need to be ApplyToEach

[image: GetPlanDetails]

Comment: Is your question about how to get the "categories" (aka labels) applied to tasks?

Comment: @SamNseir Basically got to group tasks using labels or someother way before connecting to metrics to measure progress. But there is no way to group tasks using labels unilke with Bucket.

Comment: There should be, your should find `appliedCategories` under each task property - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/planner/#gettask_response_v2

Comment: Thanks but when used "gettask", there is no specific category shown in raw output. Also, how can we group such categories ? should we use a loop & condition ?

attched the screenshot in Question

Comment: `category7` is the category, it is the "Bronze" category. You will need to go a "Get plan details" call to the get the category names set at the Planner level. You could loop or you could also try Array filter. It is going to get more tricky for you as a task could have multiple labels (categories).

Comment: Thanks Sam Nseir, however, still not getting tracked. Isnt there a way to group labels in easy way ? I have attached the screenshot of the exp.

Comment: I'm getting confused with the "group labels" aspect. What is your aim? Is it A: When a task is marked complete, find out what label it has. Or B: Get all tasks in a Plan, group them by their label. Which one, A or B or other?

Comment: Its B. transfering all the tasks grouped by labels with their current status/progress from planner to scorecard/Goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall question is pretty broad, however, I will answer your immediate need of "how to group tasks by label". Hopefully that will get you on your way.

Let me say first, I have yet to receive the new UI for Power Automate, so the following is based on the old UI. Just the same, you should be able to apply the same steps/expressions.

Here's the overview of the steps:
[image]

And the details behind each step/action:

```json
// Name: DefaultLabelNames
// Action: Data Operation > Compose
// Note: These are the default names of the categories (labels)
// Inputs:
{
  "category1": "Pink",
  "category2": "Red",
  "category3": "Yellow",
  "category4": "Green",
  "category5": "Blue",
  "category6": "Purple",
  "category7": "Bronze",
  "category8": "Lime",
  "category9": "Aqua",
  "category10": "Gray",
  "category11": "Silver",
  "category12": "Brown",
  "category13": "Cranberry",
  "category14": "Orange",
  "category15": "Peach",
  "category16": "Marigold",
  "category17": "Light green",
  "category18": "Dark green",
  "category19": "Teal",
  "category20": "Light blue",
  "category21": "Dark blue",
  "category22": "Lavender",
  "category23": "Plum",
  "category24": "Light gray",
  "category25": "Dark gray"
}
```

```js
// Name: List tasks
// Action: Planner > List tasks
// Note: Gets all the tasks for a Plan
// Inputs: Select your Group Id and Planner Id
```

```js
// Name: Get plan details
// Action: Planner > Get plan details (Preview)
// Note: Needed to get any custom renaming of labels (categories)
// Plan Id:
first(outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value'])?['planId']
```

```js
// Name: RenamedLabelNames
// Action: Data Operation > Compose
// Note: Any custom naming of the labels
// Inputs:
outputs('Get_plan_details')?['body/categoryDescriptions']
```

```js
// Name: PlanLabelNames
// Action: Data Operation > Compose
// Note: Giving the resulting label names of default and custom
// Inputs:
union(outputs('DefaultLabelNames'), outputs('RenamedLabelNames'))
```

```js
// Name: Tasks
// Action: Data Operation > Select
// Note: Array of tasks that we'll filter later on. Add each field that you need to later create the PBI Metric.
// From:
outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value']
// Map: main one here is "Label" - set it to:
outputs('PlanLabelNames')?[ coalesce(split(string(item()?['appliedCategories']), '"')?[1], 'nolabel') ]
```

[image]

```js
// Name: SelectTaskLabel
// Action: Data Operation > Select
// Note: Single field array of all the labels in all the tasks
// From:
body('Tasks')
// Map:
item()?['Label']
```

[image]

```js
// Name: UniqueLabels
// Action: Data Operation > Compose
// Note: Unique/distinct list of labels
// Inputs:
union(body('SelectTaskLabel'), body('SelectTaskLabel'))
```

```js
// Name: ForEachLabel
// Action: Control > Apply to each
// Note: Loop through each distinct label
// Inputs:
outputs('UniqueLabels')
```

[image]

```js
// Name: FilterTaskByLabel
// Action: Data Operation > Filter array
// Note: Filter previous Tasks array by label
// From:
body('Tasks')
// Condition:
item()?['Label'] /* is equal to */ items('ForEachLabel')
```

Comment: Thanks and I'm trying to replicate. However, few things are not found in new view

.... Please find the new screenshot in the question itself

Comment: You have to add `items('ForEachLabel')` as an expression in the `FilterTaskByLabel` step. The two brown "scope" steps are just placeholders to where you need to add your PBI Create Metric actions, one for the label (parent) and the other for the tasks (children).

Comment: Thanks @Sam, there seems to be Bad request, I have attached the screenshot of it in the question. Not sure why get plan details led to this.

Comment: Everything I have listed above needs to be entered as Expressions. Your `id` parameter for `Get plan details` was entered as a string and not expression. `FilterTaskByLabel` should `Filter array` action, not `Select` action.

Comment: Thanks @Sam, it seems there is some bug in my flowchart. I made in depth analysis and updated the question with 4 points. Could you please have a look once more, please. Also, could you please mention the trigger you have used.

Comment: 1. Use any trigger that your use case desires. Manal trigger works. `DefaultLabelNames` as you have it is correct. 2. Add it as a `Function`. 3. Should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyzDT.png. 4. Again use `Function` mode and use `item()?['Label']` is equal to `items('ForEachLabel')` - it should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh5O6.png

Comment: Not sure what is the use of UniqueLabels with union(body('SelectTaskLabel'), body('SelectTaskLabel'))...because union of same items. Perhaps, due to this, there is an error for the input of FilterTaskByLabel, Please find screenshot attached in question update.

Comment: `union( arrayA, arrayA )` is a Power Automate trick to remove duplicate items in an array. Here, we don't want to loop through duplicate labels.

Comment: Not sure why the error "Flow save failed with code 'WorkflowRunActionInputsInvalidProperty' and message 'The 'inputs' of workflow run action 'FilterTaskByLabel' of type 'Query' is not valid. Found properties that are not supported: 'select'.'." 
though due to this, Flow is not even saving !

Also, in GetPlan Details, automatically, ApplyToEach will pop up with 
Input: outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value']
within the loop: items('Applz?to?each')?['planId']....attached screenshot of this as well

Comment: If you entered `first(outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value'])?['planId']` as the expression for `Get plan details` then the `For each` wouldn't of shown. If you pick from the list then it will. Delete the `Apply for each` and restore back to my carefully constructed answer which I have kindly provided to you. For the `FilterTaskByLabel`, click on the `...` > `Peek code` and kindly share what it says.

Comment: Thanks Sam GetPlanDetails worked and in FiltertaskByLabel peek code is as follows:

`{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@body('Tasks')",
        "where": "@equals(item()?['Label'], items('ForEachLabel'))"
    }
}`

Comment: And can I see the Peek Code for `Tasks` please?

Comment: Peek code fot Tasks

`{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value']",
        "select": {
            "Title": "@{item()?['title']}",
            "Label": "@{outputs('PlanLabelNames')?[split(string(item()?['appliedCategories']), '\"')?[1]]}",
            "percentComplete": "@{item()?['percentComplete']}"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Also, Peek code for GetPlanDetails
`{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connectionName": "shared_planner",
            "operationId": "GetPlanDetails",
            "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_planner"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "id": "@first(outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value'])?['planId']"
        },
        "authentication": {
            "type": "Raw",
            "value": "@json(decodeBase64(triggerOutputs().headers['X-MS-APIM-Tokens']))['$ConnectionKey']"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: If you delete `FiltertaskByLabel ` and save and run, any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256118/discussion-between-abhishek-and-sam-nseir).

Comment: Not sure why '' is not recognizable.

Error in Tasks step:
InvalidTemplate. *****failed: 'The template language expression 'outputs('PlanLabelNames')?[split(string(item()?['appliedCategories']), '"')?[1]]' cannot be evaluated because property '' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

Comment: I believe that error happens when a task from Planner doesn't have a Label. Update it to `outputs('PlanLabelNames')?[ coalesce(split(string(item()?['appliedCategories']), '"')?[1], 'nolabel') ]` and it should avoid that error when no label applied on a task.

Comment: Thanks Sam, it worked :). Due to empty labels there was an issue. Is there a way to replace null with OTHERS label ? Now, metrics are created with the label names except 1 failedaction due to null label but I ACCEPT YOUR ANSWER :) Thanks for your effort. Actually, not sure how you created Sub-metric because the code for it isnt mentioned. for metric, it was straight forward : "Create a Goal" but for sub-metric, not sure !

Comment: Adding Filter after UniqueLabel with @equals(empty(item()), false) worked to remove null values from label. However, each time I test the Flow, metrics are created once again though redundantly as the scorecard is the same. Perhaps, I try "Update a Goal"or "Create a Goal". However, Creating Sub metric is sill a mystery as no actions with Sub goals or Sub metric is found :(

Comment: Replace `'nolabel'` with a default label that you would like. The answer above was assuming a one-time import from Planner to Goals - you will need to modify to check if Goal exists before creating a new one, or updating an existing one. A sub metric is just a Goal with a Parent goal id specified. At the bottom of `Create a goal` you'll see it. Add the ID from the Label metric step output from previous.